# How to safely add a key in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT and be sure it stays there?

Tags: windows, security, registry

I discovered that Windows has the bad habit of restoring some registry changes after they are made.

For example, you create few registry keys in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT and Windows does not throw any WindowsError exception. Still, on some computers they keys are removed from registry.

As you can assume, the issue does not appear when you run the application as administrator, but even so I

How can I prevent this and be sure the key is there to stay in the registry?

This happened on Windows 7 but I remember in the past having similar issues with Windows XP. At that time I was writing an installer and it was easy to require it to run as admin but now this is not the case.

Comment: how did you verify that they are "removed"? Did you consider that they never got there in the first place? There are a million reasons why... are there `Wow6432Node`s anywhere in that hive for example? Basically you can't think about a solution until you've identified the problem.

Comment: HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT isn't a real hive, which may be contributing to the problem.  Try using HKLM\Software\Classes or HKCU\Software\Classes as appropriate instead.

Answer (score 2):

Windows doesn't eat registry changes; either you have an overzealous anti-virus package (or someone is liberally screwing you by rolling back the registry) or you're getting caught up with [registry virtualization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965884.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, this is probably the cause. Now the question if hot to detect if you are affected by the registry virtualization from inside the running application? I do not want to ask for admin rights if not necessary, and I am sure that the value returned by `shell32.IsUserAnAdmin()` is not a clear indication of that.

Comment: You can use [`OpenProcessToken`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379295.aspx)/[`GetTokenInformation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446671.aspx) in advapi32 to retrieve the [`TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379626.aspx) of `TokenVirtualizationEnabled` to get a `DWORD` value that indicates whether or not the process is virtualized.